# Servlet-like behaviour with PHP?

Tags: php, servlets

I have a system consisting of a Java servlet S and another program P, running under Windows.  The servlet is fairly simple.  It starts several instances of P using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(), and uses Process.getInputStream() and Process.getOutputStream() to attach to the standard input and output of these processes.  Each instance of P has to do a significant amount of work to initialize, but that's OK because the servlet is persistent and so does not have to start new instances of P very often.  Every time the servlet receives a request it sends some text to an instance of P, which does most of the real work; it then receives some text from the standard output of P and uses it to generate a response to the request.

I would like to redo this with a wrapper written in PHP rather than Java.  That would be easy if I was willing to start a new instance of P for each request, but that would be inefficient given the startup cost.  Is there a way to emulate the servlet behaviour in PHP, and maintain a pool of instances of P that do not have to be restarted each time?

Comment: Probably not. But I would be interested if someone knows differently!

Comment: What/how much initialization needs to be done? Is that something that can be done and written to a file/database/session for future use?

Comment: @Jonathan: it would take a while to explain the context, but I have already optimized the initialization in various ways and I do not think that there is much scope to do better.

Comment: @Michael: maybe.  I have never tried using sockets.  Certainly the PHP process on the web server can do one end of a socket.  My program P does not know about sockets, but perhaps I can just wrap it in a persistent command-line PHP process running outside the web server; I'll think about that.  Thanks for the suggestion, anyway.